# Does SharePoint 2007 need IIS 6 compatibility?

Tags: 2007, iis

Just a quick one... If I'm installing SharePoint 2007 to run on top of IIS 7, do I need to enable the IIS 6 compatibility features in IIS 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually IIS6 management capability role is required. Additionally you need to be sure you have slip streamed SP1 before install or you'll have errors.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263408(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Yes in the link provided by Jesus, it says "If you use the Windows Server 2008 Server Manager to perform a default Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.0 installation, the IIS 6.0 Management Compatibility role service is not included. Since this is a required role service, you must use the following procedure[...]"

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need that...

Just make sure that you have the following IIS7 features active before you install SharePoint 2007 (for single server installation):

- Add the "Application Server" role to your server
- After that select the "Web Server (IIS)" server role.
- Select "Basic Authentication" and "Windows Authentication".
- Click next until the wizard has finished the installation process.

Comment: I've just found that without those IIS 6 compatibility features enabled I'm getting the error as described in this blog post: http://geekswithblogs.net/manesh/archive/2010/04/28/windows-server-2008-r2-ndash-moss-2007-ndash-internet-information.aspx .  Looking into it further though...